# Msbuild 4.0 is referencing System.Core 4.0 when the project targets 3.5?

Tags: .net, msbuild, bamboo

Msbuild works fine on my computer, but when I try to build the project with bamboo/msbuild it for some reason is referencing .net 4.0.

```
DB\DbExt.cs(95,42): error CS0433: The type 'System.Func<T1,T2,TResult>' exists in both 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll' and 'c:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll' [C:\Users\Administrator\bamboo-home\xml-data\build-dir\GITEXP-GITEXPORT-JOB1\NotMissing\NotMissing\NotMissing.csproj]
```

I need to use MSBuild 4.0 because I am using new compiler features (default parameters, etc). For some reason System.Core 4.0 is being referenced even though it targets 3.5.

Comment: Its the only project and doesn't reference any 4.0 assemblies. Also it builds fine outside of bamboo using msbuild 4.0.

Comment: Use the vendor's support channels, like https://answers.atlassian.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is known issue. [Link](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/558245/warning-cs1685-when-compiling-a-v3-5-net-application-in-visual-studio-2010), [Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/b2c30611-633e-4c14-9a6a-257fee9ddf6a), [Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/setupprerelease/thread/fe431ea3-4760-43b3-a5c1-2ccb2d2c158d), [Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointdevelopmentprerelease/thread/05a9eb3e-eb90-4110-98ca-6b6396ecad4a)

I fixed it by removing System.Core assembly reference from project, I think (it was long time ago).

Or try to modify your project this way:

```
<Reference Include="System.Core">
    <RequiredTargetFramework>3.5</RequiredTargetFramework>
</Reference>
```

Comment: Turns out it can't find .net 3.5 client profile. So for some reason instead of defaulting to 3.5 full it is defaulting to 4.0. At least that is my guess right now. I tried installing client profile and it still can't find it.

Comment: Another option is to install .NET 4.5 and use MSBuild 4.5 version instead of 4.0. It should be fixed in 4.5, I guess.

Comment: Thanks, adding the require to the reference element fixed it.

Comment: You can also set target framework as .Net Framework 3.5 Client Profile

Answer (score -1):

Make sure there is nothing mentioned in the Reference Paths tab of the project properties. If you want to mention the reference path of the dll here, you should make sure that the dll you are adding is present only once in the mentioned path.[image: Empty Reference Paths]